# How to prevent closing a python app in linux?

Tags: linux, python, users, raspberry-pi, qt

I am working on a project that uses a raspberry pi for it's computing purposes. It has a touch screen with it that user can choose the options from it. I want to install a light linux distro on this project.
I have written a python program that has a GUI with QT frame work (PyQt 5). 
I want to setup this linux distro to start my app when it boots and prevent user from closing this app and accessing to other OS parts. How can i do this ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look up “kiosk mode”.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about 'boot' mode, but generalizing to a user log's in and do not want them to get a command-line prompt there would be at least two possibilities:

in ~/.profile (or it's equivalent) finish with

exec myImportProgram

When the program exits, if it exits the login will stop aka logout, and a user would have to login again to restart the application.

or make 'myImportantProgram' the user's shell (as last entry in /etc/passwd)

For both of these cases you must also ensure that there is no "shell escape" that would permit to escape out of the UI and onto a command-line environment.

Not knowing more about your environment - and you do not want users to login - I would look to using the "systemd" (or inittab or /etc/rc.d/something) startup command to that it restarts of the programs ever exits - includig crashes.